curve with minimizing length is geodesic
I want to prove that if a piecewise smooth curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to M$ with the same constant speed on each segment, and it connects $p,q\in M$ and has minimal length $L(\gamma)=d(p,q)$, then it is a geodesic. I've seen the proof in many books, but most of them use concepts like uniformly normal neighborhoods or geodesic convex neihgborhoods. But I want to try another approach to the proof. I already have the following theorem:
Theorem: If $v\in T_pM$ and $\|v\|\leq \text{inj}(p)$, and let $q:=\exp_p(v)$, then $d(p,q)=\|v\|$, and a curve $\gamma$ connecting $p,q$ has minimal length $L(\gamma)=d(p,q)$, iff there is a monotonic increased reparametrization $\beta:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that $\gamma(t)=\exp_p(\beta(t)\cdot v)$.
For the proof that shortest curve is geodesic, my idea is: From the continuity of $\gamma$ and compactness of $[a,b]$, we know that its image $\Gamma:=\gamma([a,b])$ is also compact. Thus the open cover $\cup_{p\in\Gamma}\exp_p(B(0,\text{inj}(p)))$ has a finite subcover $\cup_{1\leq i\leq k}\exp_{p_i}(B(0,\text{inj}(p_i)))$. Adding the endpoints of the piecewise smooth segments, we may assume that these $p_i$ include the endpoints of the smooth segment. Let $a<t_1<\cdots<t_k<b$ such that $p_i=\gamma(t_i)$. Then, from the theorem, we know that on each $[t_i,t_{i+1}]$, the segment $\gamma|_{[t_i,t_{i+1}]}$ has minimal length, thus it has the form $\exp_{\gamma(t_i)}(\beta_i(t)\cdot v)$, where $v\in T_{\gamma(t_i)}M$ such that $\gamma(t_{i+1})=\exp_{\gamma(t_i)}(v)$. So on each $[t_i,t_{i+1}]$, $\gamma|_{[t_i,t_{i+1}]}$ is a geodesic. So if we take arbitrary $t\in [a,b]$ and if $t\in (t_i,t_{i+1})$ for some $i$, then the covariant derivative along $\gamma|_{[t_i,t_{i+1}]}$ (thus along $\gamma$) is zero. If $t=t_i$ for some $i$, then we may choose a open ball $B$ with radius $\text{inj}(\gamma(t_i))$ such that $\gamma(t_i)\in B$, and conclude that the segment of $\gamma$ in this ball is shortest, so it also must be a geodesic, so covariant derivative at $t=t_i$ is also zero. Thus, the covariant derivative is zero at every point, so $\gamma$ is geodesic.
Is my proof right, or at least feasible? Or is there any simpler or more beautiful way to prove it?

Your proof almost works but has a major flaw, that doesn't seem to be fixable without some additional argument about the smoothness of the exponential map (as for the existence of normal neighbourhoods): for all $p\in \Gamma$ you need to find a $q\in\Gamma$ different from $p$ such that $p\in\exp_q(B(0,\text{inj}(q)))$. If this happens then there is a minimising curve starting from $q$ and containing $p$ in its interior, hence a neighbourhood of $p$ in which $\gamma$ is a reparametrized geodesic.
The main problem with your approach is that at the values $t_i$ you may have a curve that is geodesic on the left and on the right, but not on a neighbourhood of $t_i$, which means that you may have a curve that is a piecewise reparametrized geodesic.
Another minor flaw is that in the first part you don't really know that the intervals $[t_i,t_{i+1}]$ are all contained in the geodesic ball centered at $t_i$ (for instance you may have $t_0=0$, $t_1=1$ and the covering $[0,1]=[0,2/3)\cup (1/3,1]$), but this is easily fixable.
Edit:
To fix your proof, we can use the fact that inj is lower semi-continuous, as it's proven here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335032/is-the-injectivity-radius-semi-continuous-on-a-non-complete-riemannian-manifol (they also prove that it's continuous, but it's easy to prove the lower semi-continuity just using the smoothness of exp in the tangent bundle). You may look everything in charts, where the smoothness of $g$ assures you that geodesic balls actually behave as deformed balls: in particular $\text{inj}\geq\text{inj}-\varepsilon$ in a neighbourhood of $p$ (all these arguments are now restricted to a chart, so inj won't necessarly be the same as in $M$, but this doesn't matter). Now the smoothness of the metric tensor $g$ assures that for some $C>0$ we have $\frac{1}{C}d_E(a,b)\leq d(a,b)\leq C d_E(a,b)$ where $d_E$ is the euclidean distance, which means that you have "big" euclidean balls inside the balls of the metric. At this point you just need to prove that $B_E(q,\delta)\subseteq \exp_q({B(0,\text{inj}(q)}))$ for some $\delta>0$ and for all $q$ in a neighbourhood of $p$. This is true because of the quantitative version of the local inversion theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) and of course the smoothness of $\text{exp}$ (in particular for the boundedness of $\text{d}^2\text{exp}$ in a compact neighbourhood of $p$). Therefore every $p\in \Gamma$ belongs to a geodesic ball of another $q\in \Gamma$ and we are done.
Since this approach requires a bit of work I don't think I consider it simpler than the traditional one, but it's true that it avoids introducing normal neighbourhoods.

I also see the first problem. So I need to show that the injective radius $inj: M\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, right?

Also in a segment I only know that $\gamma$ has the form $\exp_{\gamma(t_i)}(\beta(t)v)$, but this is not obviously a geodesic (which typical form is $\exp_{\gamma(t_i)}(tv)$). How can I fix this then?

I just edited answer for the first question, while for the second being a locally minimising curve is equivalent to being a reparametrization of a geodesic, not exactly a geodesic, so there's nothing to fix.

But then how can I use the condition that the speed of $\gamma$ is constant in each segment? I think this can determine that the curve is exactly geodesic, not just a reparametrization.

I completely missed that condition. Since our curve is a reparametrized geodesic and it's easy to see that the only reparametrized geodesics with constant speed are still geodesics (if $\gamma(t)$ is a geodesic, a reparametrization with constant speed has the form $\gamma(at)$ for some constant $a$), then for sure it's a geodesic.
